# Simple average calculator c++ not working correctly

Tags: c++, double

Hi guys I'm new to c++ but have some good experience with java.

I am trying to make a simple program that takes in 5 integers (as judges scores). The largest and smallest scores are discarded and an average must be calculated from the middle 3 scores that are left.

I thought this would be fairly simple but for some reason my program always gives me an answer slightly larger than what it should.

I should also state that the answer can be a real number while the inputs have to be integers.

Below is what I've got so far, it's pretty much complete but has some hidden schoolboy error somewhere that I haven't found for a couple hours.

I know there are probably tones of other more efficient ways to do this, but this was the best I could think of as I've only just started c++.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int getSmallest(int first, int second, int third, int fourth, int fifth);

int getLargest(int first, int second, int third, int fourth, int fifth);

double calculateAverage(int largest, int smallest, int sum);

int main()
{
    int first, second, third, fourth, fifth;
    int smallest, largest, sum;
    //double ave;

    //read input of 5 scores from judges
    cin >> first;
    cin >> second;
    cin >> third;
    cin >> fourth;
    cin >> fifth;

    smallest = getSmallest ( first, second, third, fourth, fifth );
    largest = getLargest ( first, second, third, fourth, fifth );
    sum = (first + second + third + fourth + fifth);
    //ave = calculateAverage(largest, smallest, sum);

    //cout << ave << endl;

    cout << "The average is " << (double)calculateAverage(largest, smallest, sum) << endl;

    return 0;

}

int getSmallest(int first, int second, int third, int fourth, int fifth)
{
    int smallest = 0;

    if ( first <= smallest )
    {
        smallest = first;
    }
    if ( second <= smallest )
    {
        smallest = second;
    }
    if ( third <= smallest )
    {
        smallest = third;
    }
    if ( fourth <= smallest )
    {
        smallest = fourth;
    }
    if ( fifth <= smallest )
    {
        smallest = fifth;
    }

    return smallest;
}

int getLargest(int first, int second, int third, int fourth, int fifth)
{
    int largest = 0;

    if ( first >= largest )
    {
        largest = first;
    }
    if ( second >= largest )
    {
        largest = second;
    }
    if ( third >= largest )
    {
        largest = third;
    }
    if ( fourth >= largest )
    {
        largest = fourth;
    }
    if ( fifth >= largest )
    {
        largest = fifth;
    }

    return largest;
}

double calculateAverage(int largest, int smallest, int sum)
{
    return (((double)sum) - ((double)largest + (double)smallest)) / 3.0;
}
```

Comment: What is a "hidden schoolboy error"? What is the input, expected output and actual output?

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `getSmallest` routine, you have to set

```
int smallest = INT_MAX;
```

or `smallest` will be 0 whatever you input.

(include `<climits>` for `INT_MAX` to be available)

EDIT: it works but is not efficient. You could save one test (no need for `INT_MAX` in that case) since first condition will always be true:

```
int getSmallest(int first, int second, int third, int fourth, int fifth)
{
    int smallest = first;

    if ( second <= smallest )
    {
        smallest = second;
    }
```

same optimization goes for `getLargest`

```
int getLargest(int first, int second, int third, int fourth, int fifth)
{
    int largest = first;

    if ( second >= largest )
    {
        largest = second;
    }
```